# 3D binning with R

Tags: r, 3d, binning

I have triplets cloud of points (x,y,z).
I would like to bin them and average their values in each bin. So far, I used binning function which works fine as shown in my test code:

```
n=1000
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 0.2*x + 0.5*rnorm(n)
z <- y + 0.5*rnorm(n)
x1 <- cbind(x,y,z)
xb<- binning(x1, nbins=12)
mz1<-apply(xb$table.freq, c(1,2), sum)

dim1 <- ncol(mz1)
dim2 <- length(mz1[,1])
image(1:dim1, 1:dim2, mz1, axes = TRUE, xlab="", ylab="")
```

However, instead of frequencies I wish to get average z values and instead of bins to be able to plot against x, y average values.

Can this be done with/extending binning command ?

Thank you !

Comment: When asking a question about a function in a non-base or non-recommended package you code should start with `library(pkg_name)`

Comment: I count nine different packages with a `binning` function. You should also use set.seed to fix the RNG so you could also state what you think would be the values of a particular lements in the 3d array.

Comment: @42 sorry, you are right, I forgot to mention that binning function is part of the sm package e.g. library(sm). I think set.seed is irrelevant, I would like first to get conceptually if it is possible at all.Thanks for your suggestions !